# Error in internationalization iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, internationalization

I am using iOS 5, XCODE 4.2

In my loginViewController:

```
-(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender{
    textClass=[[MainScreenController alloc ] init];
    NSLog(@"ShowText called");
    textClass.selectedLanguage=currentLanguage;
    [self.view addSubview:textClass.view] ;
    NSLog(@"txtclaslan=%d",textClass.selectedLanguage);
}
```

In my MainViewController `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
mainScreenTitle.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"screenTitle"];
```

And in `languageSelectedStringForKey:`

```
-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key{
    NSString *path;
    if(selectedLanguage==ENGLSIH_LANGUAGE)
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    else if(selectedLanguage==TURKISH_LANGUAGE)
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tr" ofType:@"lproj"];
    else
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];

    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

    NSString* str = [languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
    return str;
}
```

Here in this method `languageSelectedStringForKey` when I load the MainViewController I my application crashes. I don't get any error just this line is highlighted

```
NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];    < Thread 1
```

What can be the issue with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at your code it seems that if the language is not English and not Turkish then path is not set.

Comment: I agree with onnoweb, your 'path' variable is not set when not English or Turkish language and when you try to open a file, the apps crashes.

Comment: ok, I have added it, its not crashing now but here is one issue that the internationalization is not getting properly implemented

Comment: @onnoweb: you should make your comment an answer, because it is probably correct.  Also, note that as path is a local variable, it is a junk pointer (rather than a nil pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested:
Looking at your code it seems that if the language is not English and not Turkish then path is not set.

You may also want to follow this advice from the [NSBundle localizedStringForKey:value:table:] method description:

"Using the user default NSShowNonLocalizedStrings, you can alter the behavior of localizedStringForKey:value:table: to log a message when the method can’t find a localized string. If you set this default to YES (in the global domain or in the application’s domain), then when the method can’t find a localized string in the table, it logs a message to the console and capitalizes key before returning it."

Comment: thanx onnoweb but how to resolve the issue I am getting, that language is not getting implemented properly

Comment: Actually the issue I am facing is that, when I click on the turkish button and get login into my application it shows me the titles in turkish for a second and then these disappear and shows the titles in english again. And the second issue is that the language applied last time should remain, so that when user comes back to the application or starts the application, the language should be the last language applied. But it is not working like that.